# I want to Create a Table on submit without redirecting to any other page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I want to execute the query on Button Click with just a slide Panel(jquery) Successful Message while staying on the Same TAB.

 I have only one PAGE but different Tabs.
I am using this in my PHP code:-

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 {     header("Location: localhost/aryan/index.php");}
```

I want to stay on the same tab with just the slide panel message.

But the Problem is it always redirects to HOME tab.
I have already tried `"localhost/aryan/index.php#menu2"` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make server requests and update a page instead of navigating away, you need to use ajax. Look up into that as it's simply too broad a subject to answer here.

Comment: i have tried Ajax code too but i am not very professional and also the Ajax code did not help me. It's neither executing the SQL query nor Staying on the Same tab(redirects to Home Tab) .
Could you please Practically do this for me and Help me ?

Comment: No, I cannot do this for you. It's a big task with many different parts to know and understand. Start with reading up on ajax and go from there.